# How do I add vline to all the graphs in facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on the Boston data set and trying to see where the 8 room data are on each graph. I have commented out the line which is giving me the error.

I have to add vertical lines at all the points corresponding to rm = 8, to see the spread of data, in every graph of the grid. I want to know:
1. what I have done wrong. 
2. A better way to find/represent data points where rm = 8.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(MASS)
library(data.table)

data("Boston")
Boston <- as.data.table(Boston)

molten_boston <- Boston[, `:=`(rm = round(rm),
                                  nox = nox * 100,
                                  chas = chas * 10)]
molten_boston <- melt(data = molten_boston, id.vars = "rm")

comments_bar <- ggplot(molten_boston) + 
    geom_bar(binwidth = 1, aes(x = value), color = "black", fill = "salmon") + 
    # geom_vline(data = molten_boston[rm == 8, .SD, by = variable, .SDcols = "value"], aes(xintercept = value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
print(comments_bar)
```

Comment: This code seems to produce the expected result. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

One other visualization would be stacked bars, it looks ok when large:

```
molten_boston$EightRooms <- as.factor(molten_boston$rm == 8)
molten_boston$EightRooms <- relevel(molten_boston$EightRooms, 2)

ggplot(molten_boston, aes(x = value, fill = EightRooms)) + 
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, color = "black") + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Using a density plot in the background would be nice, but is a bit tricky in this case because of the changing y-axis. You probably have to do some pre-calculation. Here's my best attempt:

```
ggplot(molten_boston, aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_density(data = subset(molten_boston, rm == 8), aes(y =..density.. * 300),
               fill = 'blue', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, color = "black", fill = "salmon", alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be using a rug-plot, with the rugs at the top. This is more or less the same as using `geom_vline(...)` but the lines don't extend all the way down, obscuring the bars. Also, I don't see why you want to use `binwidth=1`.

```
ggplot(molten_boston) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = value), color = "grey50", fill = "salmon") + 
  geom_rug(data=molten_boston[rm==8,value, by=variable], 
           aes(x=value), sides="t", color="blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have package data.table, so I can't tell if the problem lies in the data.table part of the code or not. But you need a single value for each room size, so

```
Boston$rm = round(Boston$rm)
molten_boston <- melt(data =Boston, id.vars = "rm")
rm.means = aggregate.data.frame(molten_boston$value,by=molten_boston[,1:2],FUN=mean)
comments_bar <- ggplot(molten_boston) + 
  geom_bar(binwidth = 1, aes(x = value), color = "black", fill = "salmon") + 
  geom_vline(data = rm.means[rm.means$rm==8,], aes(xintercept = x)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")
print(comments_bar)
```

seems to work.

Comment: I think he wants to draw many vertical lines in each facet. Which the code already seems to be doing.